# UNNotificationActions Displays on iPhone but not Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, notifications, apple-watch

Working on Local notifications with Custom Actions. The notification shows on my iPhone and includes all 3 custom actions assigned to the Category.

When my iPhone is locked, the notification arrives on my Apple Watch, but the Custom Actions are not there - just the Dismiss button.

Any idea what's going on here?

Here's a code sample

```
let actionLess = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "LESS",
                                              title: "Less",
                                              options: [.foreground])
let actionMore = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "MORE",
                                              title: "More",
                                              options: [.foreground])
let action90 = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "90",
                                            title: "90min",
                                            options: [.foreground])
let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "SLEEP4B",
                                            actions: [actionLess, action90, actionMore],
                                            intentIdentifiers: [],
                                            options: .customDismissAction)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the `options` parameter in `UNNotificationAction` initialization or setting it to `.destructive` fixed it for me. You can't open the iOS app from your Apple Watch, so the foreground option will prevent the notification action from being presented on Apple Watch.